# Zod dynamic error messages based on active locale in Next.js

Tags: next.js, i18next, zod

I have an issue with i18n in Zod. Basically, I have a simple form handeled by react-hook-form and Zod for validation, but when I change the locale the error messages don't seem to be translated based on active locale.
If anyone can help me to make zod error messages dynamic. I am using Next.js, next-i18next:

```js
// my zod schema
import { z } from 'zod';
import { i18n } from 'next-i18next';

export const mailSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({
      invalid_type_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.invalid_type_error') ?? '',
      required_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.required_error') ?? '',
    })
    .email(i18n?.t('zod-errors.email') ?? ''),
  subject: z
    .string({
      invalid_type_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.invalid_type_error') ?? '',
      required_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.required_error') ?? '',
    })
    .min(3, i18n?.t('zod-errors.min') ?? '')
    .max(60, i18n?.t('zod-errors.max') ?? ''),
  body: z
    .string({
      invalid_type_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.invalid_type_error') ?? '',
      required_error: i18n?.t('zod-errors.required_error' ?? ''),
    })
    .min(10, i18n?.t('zod-errors.min') ?? '')
    .max(500, i18n?.t('zod-errors.max') ?? ''),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I found a library that provides automatic translations for zod error messages:

https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n

Comment: Could you please provide a detailed implementation of this library with the Next.js app router

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with the async loading of the messages, which is not really explained but alluded in [i18next's configuration documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#initimmediate).

I wanted to have my own error messages, not zod's translated by yet another dependency. So I did it like this:

```js
const validationSchema = z.object({
    place: z.object({
        route: z.string().min(1, "field::Address.Req").default(""),
        streetNumber: z.string().min(1, "field::Street number.Req").default(""),
        postalCode: z.string().min(1, "field::Postal code.Req").default(""),
    })
});
```

So the error messages are keys to the i18next translation machine. When rendered/presented to the user, the actual message is fetched.

In the `field` namespace, I got this:

```json
{
  "IsReq": "ist erforderlich",
  "Address.Req": "$t(common::Address) $t(field::IsReq)",
  "Street number.Req": "$t(common::Street number) $t(field::IsReq)",
  "Postal code.Req": "$t(common::Postal code) $t(field::IsReq)"
}
```

The bonus is that it is just using the system (zod | i18next), and translators can ignore the interpolation and write something better if needed.

(Adding the schema to the component would also do the trick, but that didn't feel right somehow..)

Comment: How do you deal with message parameters here (e.g. the min value of the min() function)?

Comment: @dmoebius I do not think this is possible. You will have to include the minimum required length in the message. But then again, I am open for new tricks.

Comment: I too think it's not possible now without an enhancement in Zod, e.g. like the one I proposed here: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1772#issuecomment-1709061101

Answer (score 1):

**Hey everyone!**

I am not sure if my approach is entirely correct, but I figured out a way to manage next-intl translation values/message parameters with Zod for validation errors.

Let's start with the zod schema

```js
export const signupFormStepUsernameSchema = z.object({
    username: z
        .string()
        .trim()
        .superRefine((val, ctx) => {
            const minChars = 4
            const maxChars = 20

            // ... other validation

            if (val.length < minChars) {
                ctx.addIssue({
                    code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
                    message: `errors.invalid.username.minLength|{"min": ${minChars}}`,
                })

                return z.NEVER
            }
            if (val.length > maxChars) {
                ctx.addIssue({
                    code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
                    message: `errors.invalid.username.maxLength|{"max": ${maxChars}}`,
                })

                return z.NEVER
            }

            // ... other validation

        }),
}).strict().required();
```

Let's break down what we are passing or in what format we are passing the error message:

```js
ctx.addIssue({
    code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
    message: `errors.invalid.username.maxLength|{"max": ${maxChars}}`
});
```

In the message, we defined a specific format and separated the message key and translation values/message parameters with the `|` symbol.

In the implementation section, we extract key and translation values/message parameters by the following methods.

Firstly let me mention the necessary imports and typing declarations

```js
import { MessageKeys, TranslationValues } from "next-intl"

type ComponentSignupMessages =
  typeof import("./i18n/en-US/components/signup.json");
type Messages = ComponentSignupMessages;
type ZNIMNestedValueOf<
  T,
  K extends Extract<keyof T, string>
> = K extends keyof T
  ? T[K] extends Record<string, any>
    ? `${K}.${ZNIMNestedKeys<T[K]>}`
    : `${K}`
  : never;

type ZNIMNestedKeys<T> = NestedValueOf<T, Extract<keyof T, string>>;
interface IntlMessages extends Messages {}
```

Okay, now let's get to the work.

- First, we store the error message in a variable:

```js
const dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues: Array<string> = errors.username ? (errors.username.message as string).split("|"): "|".split("|");
```

The above line of code checks if there's an error message associated with the username field. If there is, it splits the error message by `|` and stores the resulting parts in an array named dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues. If there's no error, it creates an array with an empty string.

- Then we extract the message key from the error message:

```js
let refinedErrorKey = "" as MessageKeys<
  ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"],
  ZNIMNestedKeys<ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"]>
>;

if (
  (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as string) &&
  (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as string).length > 0
) {
  refinedErrorKey = dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as MessageKeys<
    ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"],
    ZNIMNestedKeys<ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"]>
  >;
}
```

The above code initializes a variable called refinedErrorKey as an empty string. It then checks if the first element of dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues array (assumed to be a string) exists and has a length greater than zero. If true, it assigns the value of the first element of dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues to refinedErrorKey.

- Then we extract the translation values/message parameters from the error message:

```js
let refinedTranslationValues = {} as TranslationValues;

if (
  (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1] as string) &&
  (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1] as string).length > 0
) {
  refinedTranslationValues = JSON.parse(
    dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1]
  ) as TranslationValues;
}
```

The above code initializes a variable named refinedTranslationValues as an empty object. It then checks if the second element of the dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues array (expected to be a string) exists and has a length greater than zero. If true, it parses the second element of dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues as JSON and assigns the resulting object to refinedTranslationValues.

- After doing all the previous staff we can use it like:

```js
<p>
  {errors.username
    ? t(
        refinedErrorKey,
        Object.keys(refinedTranslationValues).length === 0
          ? undefined
          : refinedTranslationValues
      )
    : " "}
</p>
```

Here, if there's an error message associated with the username (errors.username), it invokes a translation function t() with parameters refinedErrorKey and refinedTranslationValues, unless refinedTranslationValues is empty. If there's no error message for the username, it renders an empty space.

#### Practical example of all these above implementations in a `helperText` of `<TextField/>` of MUI React Component

```js
<TextField
  name="username"
  variant="outlined"
  autoComplete="off"
  autoCorrect="off"
  label={t("label.username")}
  id="username"
  error={!!errors.username}
  helperText={(() => {
    const dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues: Array<string> = errors.username
      ? (errors.username.message as string).split("|")
      : "|".split("|");
    let refinedErrorKey = "" as MessageKeys<
      ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"],
      ZNIMNestedKeys<ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"]>
    >;
    let refinedTranslationValues = {} as TranslationValues;
    if (
      (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as string) &&
      (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as string).length > 0
    ) {
      refinedErrorKey = dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[0] as MessageKeys<
        ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"],
        ZNIMNestedKeys<ComponentSignupMessages["Signup"]["StepUsername"]>
      >;
    }
    if (
      (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1] as string) &&
      (dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1] as string).length > 0
    ) {
      refinedTranslationValues = JSON.parse(
        dirtyErrorKeyAndTranslationValues[1]
      ) as TranslationValues;
    }
    return errors.username
      ? t(
          refinedErrorKey,
          Object.keys(refinedTranslationValues).length === 0
            ? refinedTranslationValues
            : undefined
        )
      : " ";
  })()}
  fullWidth
/>
```

## Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it very simply! In a Zod object, as an error message, I put just the translation key, and the actual t('key') is done in the error message component. No library needed, no additional work at all. Hope you enjoy the easy fix :)

❌ wrong

```
email: z.string().email({ message:  t('emailError)})
```

✅ Correct!

```
email: z.string().email({ message: 'emailError'})
```

Then use like so:

```
<HelperText type='error'>
   {t(errors.email.message)}
</HelperText>
```

Comment: That's the same solution that geertjanvdk outlined. You cannot easiliy transfer message parameters with this, except by adding it to the message string, e.g. "message: 'minLengthRequired,5'" and then extracting the parameter before passing it to the $t() translation function.